# How to host .NET Core webapp in MacBook Pro using apache

Tags: apache, asp.net-core-webapi, macos-big-sur

I want to host my Asp .Net Core Web Api on MacOs(Big Sur) with Apache.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps**

1. [Install .Net SDK on MacOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos).
2. [Configure Apache - Map Your IP address to localhost](https://wpbeaches.com/set-up-virtual-hosts-on-macos-big-sur-11-in-apache/)
3. [Create your webapp and publish it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-5.0#publish-and-copy-over-the-app)

**Suggestion**

1. Read the steps of hosting webapp on linux.
2. Understand how to use apache to use webapp (.netcore,php,and java...)